# Как устранить ошибку InternalError: too much recursion?

Tags: javascript, вконтакте, рекурсия, отладка, webworkers

Разбираюсь с web workers, пишу приложение ([github](https://github.com/Deserter-io/vkListr)) для скачивания списка Участников группы ВКонтакте. Авторизация и получение id группы происходит во «фронтенде», а долгое скачивание поручается "рабочему" – [dedicated web worker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers#Dedicated_workers)'у.

На группах до 3.5 млн. работает. Но попробовал MDK с их 7 млн. и напоролся на ошибку в консоли: `InternalError: too much recursion`. Firefox 41.0.1, os x 10.11.

**Как точнее разобраться в причине этой ошибки?**

Может ли это быть лимит памяти данных (предполагаю, около 70 мегов весят id в текстовом виде)? Или дело в том, как я криво организовал вызовы к api – накручивается где-то снежный ком коллбэков?

**Воспроизвести ошибку** можно [тут](https://deserter-io.github.io/vkListr/): авторизоваться через ВК и ввести группу `mdk`. У меня отваливается на 65–71%.

Запросы к API ВКонтакта делаю через *jsonp*: формирую url запроса и добавляю параметр `callback` с именем функции, которую вызвать «по возвращении». И выполняю `importScripts()` с этим url.

Весь код обернул в объект, который вешает свой метод на обработку коллбэка:

```
self.callback = this.runLoop.bind(this);
```

Может, эта конструкция создаёт лишний виток стека вызовов?

Буду благодарен за идеи по дебагу воркера, а также помощь в отлаживании проекта.

Comment: Проблема, я так понимаю, в `importScripts` - вы запускаете его в `runLoop`, затем не выходя из него опять вызывается этот же метод и т.д. Не пробовали обращаться к ВК асинхронно, через тот же ajax? Тогда запуск метода всегда был бы "чистым", т.е. безо всякой рекрсии

Comment: Через `XMLHttpRequest` не выйдет т.к. cross-domain. Поэтому jsonp c `importScripts()`. Он асинхронен.

Comment: Напишите после `importScripts ` строчку `console.log(1);` и поставьте на ней breakpoint. Как думаете - когда у вас он сработает? И о какой асинхронности вы говорите? Нет асинхронности, есть синхронность, есть лимит рекурсии, в который вы упираетесь

Comment: 1. Написал. В консоль сыпятся выводы **по ходу** считывания большой группы – т.е. туда выполнение доходит, и ф-я завершается.  2. каким дебаггером можно поставить breakpoint внутри кода web worker'а? FireBug внутрь WW не умеет.

Comment: Я хромом пользуюсь. Поставил брекпоинт на importScripts, поставил на console.log. Доходит до importScripts и опять до него и опять до него и т.д. Т.е. console.log будет достигнут только при возврате из рекурсии. Обернул importScripts в `setTimeout(function() {importScripts (url);}, 100)` - дошел до 100%, т.е. как раз сделал то, что предлагал - обращение к вк происходит асинхронно

Comment: Гениально! Спасибо, это помогло. А насчет `console.log` – может, Spidermonkey и V8 по-разному имплементировали `importScripts()` в части порядка выполнения импортированных скриптов и выхода из ф-ии?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Похоже, я не учёл, что `importScripts()` не только импортирует скрипт, но и немедленно его исполняет, ещё до выхода из функции. Это вызывает ком вложенности вызовов метода `runLoop()`, что и переполняет стек.

[Fixed](https://github.com/Deserter-io/vkListr/commit/d71e192597898c125e480800b8244f742ac3cb63) обёртыванием в `setTimeout()`:

```
setTimeout( function(){ importScripts(url)}, 0);
```

Спасибо @BOPOH за обнаружение и объяснение этого момента.