# получить видео с access_key из вконтакте

Tags: vkontakte-api

В [документации вконтакте](https://vk.com/dev/video.get) написано:

Некоторые видеозаписи, идентификаторы которых могут быть получены через API, закрыты приватностью, и не будут получены. В этом случае следует использовать ключ доступа access_key в её идентификаторе.

Каким путем достать этот access_key?

В документациях не могу найти такую информацию.

Comment: Так там же где это написано, там и [ссылка](https://vk.com/dev/access_key) на этот access_token. Т.е. получаете его когда список видео получаете, там даже пример есть

Comment: @ВОРОН, некоторые получаются, но некоторые видео получать  не получается так, как требует access_key (я так думаю). Конечно пробовал получать списком, где вы там видите access_key, нету там? Где то в форуме читал, что для фото, чтоб получить access_key нужно делать запрос в photos.getById, но в видео нет такого метода.

Comment: Будет проще, если вы рабочий пример создадите, например, как в [этом вопросе](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/456063/5079), т.к. в доках пишут что все просто: *При получении объектов, прямого доступа к которым может не быть, например, фотографий или видео в новостях, вместе с объектами приходит поле access_key, которое необходимо передавать при получении этих объектов напрямую или при совершении с ними действий* Т.е. access_key для таких видео должен сам приходить когда запрашиваете список видео (вы же откуда-то узнали об этом идентификаторе)

Comment: И, кстати, [объект видео](https://vk.com/dev/video_object) содержит access_token только если используется версия апи 5+, если версия ниже, то это поле не приходит

Answer (score 2):

`Access_key` можно получить с помощью метода `newsfeed.get` в параметрах указав,   `filters = post` и `count = 1`. В ответе будет помимо информации о посте, `access_key`.
Пример ответа:

```
    {
  "response": {
    "items": [
      {
        "type": "post",
        "source_id": -57846937,
        "date": 1467650412,
        "post_id": 2809380,
        "post_type": "post",
        "text": "",
        "attachment": {
          "type": "photo",
          "photo": {
            "pid": 418453269,
            "aid": -7,
            "owner_id": -57846937,
            "user_id": 100,
            "src": "http://cs7005.vk.me/v7005482/2a266/ykQqTloRWy8.jpg",
            "src_big": "http://cs7005.vk.me/v7005482/2a267/2O00C6MUGxc.jpg",
            "src_small": "http://cs7005.vk.me/v7005482/2a265/Aq7yK_-gQ_U.jpg",
            "width": 480,
            "height": 423,
            "text": "",
            "created": 1467648178,
            "post_id": 2809380,
            "access_key": "18d3696d47dd4867a3"  <== KEY
          }
        },
// Остальной код 
}
```